# Automation of documents creation in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working with word on realizing documentation for a project that involves several locations around the country. The documents I am required to produce are basically the same for each and every site, with only a few key areas changing, such as site name, the locations of certain devices within the site, the address of the site and so on.

This seemed fairly easy to achieve with word mailing merge feature however, one of the areas I have to customize is an image that shows the planimetry of each site and has to obviously be different from each and every file. I don't have the slightest clue on how to get word to automatically pull images from a folder and, have them inserted into a document.

Is it possible to automatically achieve what I ask? If so could anyone point me out to a resource to learn to do that? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Consider phrasing your question in a more clear way. For eg.: project involves several sites - do you mean locations? Please make it easy to understand.

Comment: [This](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_archive/mail-merge-with-variable-pictures-using-word-2013/32c9b910-06b8-4b9e-80eb-ccd39c22afa4) may help.

Comment: Apologies, english ain't my first language. Yes, there are several locations around my country, the project for each of these locations are basically the same with just the key areas outlined above changing. 

I can change these rather easily with the mail merge feature, what i am puzzled about is how I go about inserting a different image at a certain point in the document that is different for each file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell to create Word files.

https://techblog.dorogin.com/generate-word-documents-with-powershell-cda654b9cb0e

The above example will read in a text document and create a word document out of it.

I've not done this before but it looks reasonably straight forward. I'm sure google will tell you how to include a picture.

Answer (score 0):

It is said that Access 97 programs can also be run by newer versions of Access.
This
[post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_mobile-msoversion_other/access-97-windows-7/d1a92707-5bea-437d-b9e8-01b17b98182b)
for example mentions Access 2010.

You will find a detailed report on how to do the installation in the article
[Running Access 97 on Windows 7](http://nwsmith.blogspot.com/2010/07/running-access-97-on-windows-7.html).

There are even reports of people who managed to get Access 97 running on Windows 10 ...

However, the best way to conserve a working environment for an old program
is to use a virtual machine. This way it is guaranteed to work for as long as
required.